# Find the values in table with cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have a table with one column id and this column have (1,2,3,5,8,12,15,20)
i have find values that not in table WHIT CURSOR 
this is a practice for Cursor
my query had error
please help me

---

```
declare cur cursor for select id from T7
open cur
    declare @id int
    declare @show1 int
    declare @show2 int
    declare @temp table (number int)
    fetch next from cur into @id
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        set  @show1 = @id
        fetch next from cur into @id
            set  @show2 = @id 
            if @show2 - @show1 = 1 
            begin
                print 'true'
            end
            while @show2 - @show1 !=1
            begin
                set @show2 = @show2 - 1
                insert into @temp select @show2
            end
    end
    select * from @temp order by number asc
close cur
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time determining what you are trying to accomplish with this procedure. Could you please edit your question to add the actual goal of this code? (i.e. what is the desired output?)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking
I do not have the numbers in this table
example values (4,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,16,17,18,19) in table temp